# Is there a way to collapse two columns to one in gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Am trying to collapse to columns in order to have a single column so as to suit a given table structure. The desired output is to be for 23 (21.2 - 24.5). I have the two tables already created but I don't seem to get it. In essence I would like the proportions and CI to be in a single column with just one title **% (95% CI)**

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

# Obtain proportions

tbl1 <-
  trial %>%
  mutate(trt = as.factor(trt)) %>%
  select(grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(missing = "no",  type = everything() ~ "categorical",
              statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}")

myci2 <-
  tbl1$meta_data %>%
  filter(summary_type %in% c("categorical", "dichotomous")) %>%
  select(summary_type, var_label, df_stats) %>%
  unnest(df_stats) %>%
  mutate(
    conf.low = (p - qnorm(0.975) * sqrt(p * (1 - p) / N)) %>%
      style_percent(symbol = TRUE),
    conf.high =( p + qnorm(0.975) * sqrt(p * (1 - p) / N)) %>%
      style_percent(symbol = TRUE),
    ci = str_glue("{conf.low}, {conf.high}"),
    label = coalesce(variable_levels, var_label),
    row_type = ifelse(summary_type == "dichotomous", "label", "level")
  ) %>%
  select(variable, row_type, label, ci)


finaltbl <-
  tbl1 %>%
  modify_table_body(
    left_join,
    myci2,
    by = c("variable", "row_type", "label")
  ) %>%
  modify_header(ci = "**% (95% CI)**")

finaltbl

finaltbl[["table_body"]] <- finaltbl[["table_body"]] %>%
  mutate(prev = paste0(stat_0, " (", ci, ")")) 


finaltbl %>% 
  modify_column_unhide(prev) %>% 
  modify_column_hide(c(stat_0, ci))
```

Comment: Why don't  you just `dplyr::unite` the two colums *before* passing the data to `gtsummary`?

Comment: Am giving it a try but seemingly getting the error

Comment: Am trying to modify the table body but seems not be working. Let me check

Error in unite(stat_0, ci) : object 'stat_0' not found

Comment: Where does that `stat_0` comes from? You should manipulate your data *before* passing them to `gtsummary`. I think you've got all you need in the `trial` dataframe (if that's a dataframe), post it so we can take a look at what's in there and suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.1
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.2.9008'

# Obtain proportions
tbl1 <-
  trial %>%
  mutate(trt = as.factor(trt)) %>%
  select(grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(missing = "no",  type = everything() ~ "categorical",
              statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}%")

myci2 <-
  tbl1$meta_data %>%
  filter(summary_type %in% c("categorical", "dichotomous")) %>%
  select(summary_type, var_label, df_stats) %>%
  unnest(df_stats) %>%
  mutate(
    conf.low = (p - qnorm(0.975) * sqrt(p * (1 - p) / N)) %>%
      style_percent(symbol = TRUE),
    conf.high =( p + qnorm(0.975) * sqrt(p * (1 - p) / N)) %>%
      style_percent(symbol = TRUE),
    ci = str_glue("{style_percent(p)}% ({conf.low}, {conf.high})"),
    label = coalesce(variable_levels, var_label),
    row_type = ifelse(summary_type == "dichotomous", "label", "level")
  ) %>%
  select(variable, row_type, label, ci)


finaltbl <-
  tbl1 %>%
  modify_table_body(
    left_join,
    myci2,
    by = c("variable", "row_type", "label")
  ) %>%
  modify_header(ci = "**% (95% CI)**") %>%
  modify_column_hide(stat_0)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Perfect! This helps a million times!

Comment: FYI, merging columns will be easier in the next release with this function http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/dev/reference/modify_cols_merge.html